# Installing numba onto Linux 7.0 - error with prerequisite llvmlite library diectory

Tags: python, linux, jit, spyder, numba

I'm new to Linux and generally installing packages via command line syntax.

I've tried installing numba (to use jit) into Python and this is the error I receive.I did this originally with GitHub source, and again with Anaconda. Numba appear to be installed correctly in the command line, however when I try to import into Spyder I get the below error

llvmlite imports without error.

```
>>> import numba
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numba-0.22.1_13.g1902d7f-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/numba/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from . import testing, decorators
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numba-0.22.1_13.g1902d7f-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/numba/testing.py", line 6, in <module>
    from numba import config
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numba-0.22.1_13.g1902d7f-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/numba/config.py", line 9, in <module>
    import llvmlite.binding as ll
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/llvmlite-0.0.0-py2.7.egg/llvmlite/binding/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .dylib import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/llvmlite-0.0.0-py2.7.egg/llvmlite/binding/dylib.py", line 4, in <module>
    from . import ffi
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/llvmlite-0.0.0-py2.7.egg/llvmlite/binding/ffi.py", line 43, in <module>
    lib = ctypes.CDLL(_lib_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 365, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: libllvmlite.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: How did you install numba? Did you explicitly install llvmlite? Generally, the easiest way to get numba (as well as scientific packages for python) is to use Anaconda/Miniconda (https://www.continuum.io/downloads). Otherwise, see the install instructions: http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/installing.html

Comment: I cloned the relevant files from their GitHub sources and did `python setup.py install`

Comment: I've installed numbas via Anaconda now, and in the terminal window it imports fine. However importing jit (numba) through Spyder still gets the same error

Comment: Got the same problem. What really confuses me: When I try to debug into it, I get all local variables shown as `None` for all of the frames within the `llvmlite` import. Though, ctypes seems to be called fine, and the library is there in the same directory.